# Android CDATA parsing with SAX, tag not removed

Tags: android, xml, sax, cdata

My xml contains some cdata

```
<desc><![CDATA[<p>This is my html text</p>]]></desc>
```

My SAX parser is able to parse the xml cdata but the parsed text contains the tag 'CDATA'

```
<![CDATA[<p>This is my html text</p>]]>
```

I would like to get only the html text inside the CDATA. I can use some string functions to remove that but I would like to know whether this is normal SAX behavior?

This is my SAX Handler code:

```
public class SAXXMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {
private List<Laptop> laptops;
private Laptop laptop;
private StringBuffer tempSB = new StringBuffer();

public SAXXMLHandler() {
    laptops = new ArrayList<Laptop>();
}

public List<Laptop> getLaptops() {
    return laptops;
}

// Event Handlers
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    tempSB.delete(0, tempSB.length());
    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("laptop")) {
        laptop = new Laptop();
        laptop.setModel(attributes.getValue("model"));
    }
}       

public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
    tempSB.append(ch, start, length);
}  

public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("laptop")) {
        laptops.add(laptop);
    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("id")) {
        laptop.setId(Integer.parseInt(tempSB.toString()));
    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("desc")) {
        laptop.setDescription(tempSB.toString());
    } 
}
}
```

Comment: No, this is not the way SAX is specified to behave. It should return the stuff between `"<![CDATA["` and `"]]>"` in one or more calls to the characters() callback.

Comment: Then what could be the problem. I added my SAX Handler code.

Answer (score 0):

Please check for "<*p*>", you can set up a boolean which when reached CDATA will be true like this you can distinguish between "<*p*>" tag in CDATA and common "<*p*>".